# Identical Flutter Widgets in Row throwing error?

Tags: routes, widget, row, flutter

I'm producing 2 FloatingActionButtons within a Row.  I'm getting the following error when routing to its file...

> The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
>       There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
>       Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (typically a PageRoute subtree), each Hero
>       must have a unique non-null tag.
>       In this case, multiple heroes had the tag "Instance of 'Object'".

Here is my code...

```
new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new FloatingActionButton(
                    child: new Icon(Icons.remove), onPressed: _decline),
                new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
                new Text(
                  _count.toString(),
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 40.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black),
                ),
                new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
                new FloatingActionButton(
                    child: new Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: _increment),
              ],
            )
```

This is how I'm routing to my file...

`Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => new Video.VideoPage()));`

When I comment out the first FloatingActionButton it works fine.  It only errors out when they're both used.  My `Row` is also a child of a `Column` widget if that matters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding a unique [`heroTag`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton/heroTag.html) for each of the `FloatingActionButton`s, so that Flutter does not confuse the two button with each other, something like:

```
new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: "Decline",
              child: new Icon(Icons.remove), onPressed: _decline),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
          new Text(
            _count.toString(),
            style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 40.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black),
          ),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
          new FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: "Increment",
              child: new Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: _increment),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: I have no `FloatingActionButton` in my entire project but still getting this error when I navigate from child to parent screen. Please suggest me what is the solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Same issue. @Kamlesh have got the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use more than one floating action button on the same page so there are two possibilities.

1. Don't use more than one floating action button (Flutter is awesome
   so    there are other ways to get the same result)
2. Don't leave heroTag null.

Comment: I have no `FloatingActionButton` in my entire project but still getting this error when I navigate from child to parent screen. Please suggest me what is the solution? Thanks a lot.